Plot vertex attributes
I have a dataframe "dfmin" of individuals and their connections to each other. Accompanying that, I also have another dataframe which metadata on these individuals. Below is minimum code example of what I mean. I want to be able to make simple plot.igraph() visualisations and, for example, give different colors to vertices according to some of the attributes in the metadata object "dfmin.attr"
sec <- 1:10
id <- paste("id", sec, sep = "")

dfmin <- data.frame(c("id2", "id3", "id6", rep(NA, 7)),
                    c("id1", "id7", "id9", "id10", "id4", rep(NA, 5)),
                    c("id2", "id1", rep(NA, 8)),
                    c("id6", "id2", rep(NA, 8)),
                    c("id4", rep(NA, 9)),
                    c("id7", "id1", "id3", rep(NA, 7)),
                    c("id2", rep(NA, 9)),
                    c("id4", "id10", rep(NA, 8)),
                    c("id4", "id5", "id7", "id2", rep(NA, 6)),
                    c("id3", rep(NA,9))
)

colnames(dfmin) <- id


dfmin.attr <- data.frame(id = id, coo = c("AUT", "AUT", "AUT", "GER", "FRA", "FRA", "POL", "AUT", "AUT", "USA"),
                         female = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0))

What I don't understand is that there is this option of specifying vertex information in the graph_from_data_frame(vertices = NULL) command, which seems to me is a way of linking the two dataframes (the network and the metadata) together, such that the attributes of the individuals in the network dfmin are now merged to their metadata information in "dfmin.attr". I create the network object with g <- graph_from_data_frame(na.omit(stack(dfmin)), directed = FALSE, vertices = dfmin.attr) and the attributes from dfmin.attr are linked to g just how I want it.
Is there a way to easily plot the network with and specify that verticies should be coloured according to information in the metadata? Let's say I wsant to have the vertices to have different colors then I would want something that works similar to the option of group, fill or color as I would have in ggplot.
This is so straightforward in ggplot but not with networks apparently: plot.igraph(g, vertex.color = female) wouldn't work.
I've seen and have found solutions but they are quite long and sometimes not feasible where you specify one color to each level in a metadata variable, for example: country_colors <- c(AUT = "blue", GER = "red", FRA = "green", POL = "orange", USA = "purple")  if I were to plot the network and color each vertex by "coo" country of origin and then plot with plot(g, vertex.color = country_colors[dfmin.attr$coo]) but this is not feasible for large numbers of countries for example.
Help will be massively appreciated!

First of all, the attribute you want to demonstrate is the vertex attribute (another attribute is the edge attribute), so you should specify V(g)$female in your example.

You can try factor to specify different colors for different coo values, e.g.,
graph_from_data_frame(na.omit(stack(dfmin)), FALSE, dfmin.attr) %>%
    plot(vertex.color = factor(V(.)$coo))



Oh that's exactly how I thought it should work but when I tried it I must've continuously made a small mistake and I always got a NULL response. Okay, case close. thank you!
